# How to use SKNode fileNamed: initializer on any node that is not an SKScene

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I have asked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066375/loading-an-sknode-from-a-sks-scene-file-in-swift) a while ago, but since then it seems `SKNode` now has this nifty initializer `init?(fileNamed filename: String)` that unarchives the scene from an .sks file.  The thing is, this initializer is on `SKNode`, not `SKScene`, so I am trying (mostly out of programmer curiosity) to use it on a node, any node, that is not `SKScene` or a subclass of it.

Now I know I can put the node I want as a child of the .sks file, load the scene using `SKNode(fileNamed:...` and then pull out the node using `childNode(withName:...`.  But since the `fileNamed` initializer is declared for `SKNode`, you should be able to directly load an `SKNode` and cut out the `SKScene` middle man.  If this is not possible, then why wouldn't the initializer be declared in `SKScene`?

So, I have tried this, but it appears the root node for the .sks file is strongly suggested to be a descendant of `SKScene` as seen in this dialog box:

[image]

Ignoring caution, I made an .sks file that looks like this:

[image]

I made the root Scene be a custom class of an `SKNode` subclass, and I got this build error:

```
[MyProject.SolarSystemNode setBlendMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is because the `blendMode` property is declared on `SKEffectNode`.  The class inheritance goes `SKNode` -> `SKEffectNode` -> `SKScene`.  So apparently the `fileNamed:` initializer, though declared on `SKNode` calls a property on `SKEffectNode`.

So, is it possible to load an `SKNode` directly, or am I stuck arranging my node tree like this:

[image]

and loading the scene first then pulling out the solarSystemNode?  If it is possible to load an `SKNode` directly from an .sks file with the `fileNamed` initializer, then could someone please show me an example how, preferably in Swift 3?  If it is not possible, could someone please tell me why the `fileNamed` initializer would be declared on `SKNode` and not `SKScene`?

Comment: too drunk to give a proper answer, but isn't this what `SKReferenceNode` is for?  https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skreferencenode

Comment: @Fluidity Thank you!  I have been meaning to delve into `SKReferenceNode`.  I am having a hard time finding documentation or a tutorial that shows you how to set it up in the scene editor **AND** how to properly load it from code.  Most show it exclusively in the editor, and the few that show it programmatically, don't show how it was set up in the editor.  When they show one, it leaves me wondering exactly how they set up the other.  If you find yourself sober with some free time, could you give me a demo, or point me to a complete tutorial?  Either way, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Fluidity I should mention, I starting playing around with it, and caused xcode to crash and refuse to reopen even after I rebooted.  I had to delete the sprite kit scene file before Xcode would open my project.  I think I caused the reference node to reference its containing scene.  Guess Xcode doesn't like infinite loops!

Comment: i will write something here soon. msg me back in a day if i forget xD